# Android: Create and Download PDF files to Downloads directory

Tags: android, pdf

In my Android App, in one of the activity, there is a "PDF Download" button. When this button is clicked, I create a PDF and then download it to the "Downloads" directory. Following is my code which runs on the click event of the button:

```
    public void createAndDownloadPDF()
    {
        try
        {
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
            View content = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(content.getWidth(),
                    content.getHeight() - 20, 1).create();
            PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
            content.draw(page.getCanvas());
            document.finishPage(page);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
            String pdfName = "pdfdemo"
                    + sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + ".pdf";
            File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), pdfName);

            try
            {
                outputFile.createNewFile();
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                document.writeTo(out);
                document.close();
                out.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Please note that I added the required WRITE permission to the MANIFEST file and also asking for the permission at runtime. So, there is no issue of permissions.

When I debug the code, I notice that "`outputFile`" variable holds this path:

```
/storage/emulated/o/Download/pdfdemo07052017121233.pdf
```

My users will never find above path in their mobile. So, they will have no clue where their PDF got saved. I want that when users click on "Downloads" icon on their mobile, they should see the PDF file they downloaded from the app.

So, I think if I can sort out the following line:

```
File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), pdfName);
```

my work will be done. What should be the path I use so that my PDF files get saved / downloaded in the "Downloads" directory? I researched over the internet, but did not find any concrete solution.

Comment: Well the folder you use is the right folder. But the reason your users dont see your file in the right folder is that the Downloads app not just looks in that folder for files. Probably it queries the MediaStore for files. Do the users see your file after switching device off/on?

Comment: For the rest i think it is a bad idea to put a file that you create yourself in the public Download folder. It is not downloaded to begin with isnt it?

Comment: `createAndDownloadPDF()`? Wrong function name. You are not downloading are you?

Comment: With a normal File Explorer app you should be able to see your pdf file in the mentioned folder. Now do you?

Comment: Further you should have told us if indeed the file gets created. Why did not you inform us?

Comment: You should place a Toast in all catch blocks! Ditto an e.printStackTrace();

Comment: `My users will never find above path in their mobile.`. Why not? Every File Explorer app can display that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    File outDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());
```

If this doesn't work, evaluate the chance of having your PDF file previously generated and saved into a folder inside your Assets folder. If this can be the case, after the above line you insert this:

```
    copyAssets("XXX",outDir.toString());
```

Where "XXX" is the name of the folder inside your Assets folder which will contain the PDF file. This will copy the contents of XXX to `DOWNLOADS/XXX` on your device.

Comment: It is getting same path. No effect.

Comment: Note that my syntax `File outDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());` is to create a folder. You are trying to use almost the same to create a file.